# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run JUnit 5 tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit5

I have the following error when trying to run a simple JUnit 5 test (eclipse):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I've tried some suggestions on similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040675/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-junit-platform-commons-preconditionviolation), [this github issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1773) and others, but without success. I'm still learning JUnit so I may be forgetting something obvious.

Comment: The issue here is to use junit-jupiter-engine as dependency as described here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Comment: What happens if you add a `test` scoped dependency on `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher` version 1.4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to add the JUnit 5 library to my build path, now it works perfectly.