# "No test were found" with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I tried to run my first test and this problem appeared and I have no clue how to correct it

here is the test code

```
package g59474.dev2.model;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class GridTest {

    @Test
    void firstAdd_CaseA() {
        System.out.println("Case A");
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        Tile t1 = new Tile(Color.RED, Shape.ROUND);
        Tile t2 = new Tile(Color.RED, Shape.DIAMOND);
        Tile t3 = new Tile(Color.RED, Shape.PLUS);
        grid.firstAdd(Direction.UP, t1, t2, t3);

        assertEquals(t1, grid.get(45,45));
        assertEquals(t2, grid.get(44,45));
        assertEquals(t3, grid.get(43,45));
    }
}
```

And here the error
I don't understand what these mean so I don't really now what i need to check

```
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDirFactory
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.DefaultJupiterConfiguration.<clinit>(DefaultJupiterConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDirFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 16 more
```

Thanks to all people willing to help me.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040675/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-junit-platform-commons-preconditionviolation help?

Comment: Check all your junit dependencies. You probably mixing 5.10 artifacts with 5.9 artifacts.